# R formula: wrap all variables in a transformation

Tags: r

I have a formula with an arbitrary number of variables on the left and right-hand sides:

```r
a + b * c ~ d + e
```

This formula can include various operators like `+` or `*`. I would like to wrap each variable of the formula in a transformation. For example, if my transformation is called `Factor`, then the formula above becomes:

```r
Factor(a) + Factor(b) * Factor(c) ~ Factor(d) + Factor(e)
```

Notice that it preserved the same signs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) rrapply** We can use `rrapply` to recursively walk the formula and surround every node that is a syntactic name with `Factor(...)`.  Alternately we could use `is.word <- function(x) grepl("^\\w+$", x)` to check for names that only contain word characters.

```
library(rrapply)
fo <- a + b * c ~ d + e

is.word <- function(x) make.names(x) == x
insert.Factor <- function(x) substitute(Factor(x), list(x = x))

rrapply(fo, is.word, insert.Factor)
## Factor(a) + Factor(b) * Factor(c) ~ Factor(d) + Factor(e)
```

If we can have formulas such as

```
fo2 <- a + b * c ~ I(d) + e
```

and we want I(Factor(d)) rather than Factor(I)(Factor(d)) then use this for `is.word`:

```
is.word <- function(x) make.names(x) == x && format(x) %in% all.vars(fo2)
```

**2) gsub**  Convert to character string, perform the substitution and convert back.  The input, `fo`, is defined above.

```
formula(gsub("(\\w+)", "Factor(\\1)", format(fo)), environment(fo))
## Factor(a) + Factor(b) * Factor(c) ~ Factor(d) + Factor(e)
```

**3) Transform data frame** If these variables will be obtained from a data frame DF then we could transform its columns and leave the formula as is.

```
DF[] <- lapply(DF, Factor)
```

Comment: An amazing function!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to update a formula with a recursive function:

```
update_formula <- function(x){
    if(length(x) == 3){
        x[[2]] <- update_formula(x[[2]])
        x[[3]] <- update_formula(x[[3]])
        return(x)
    }else{
        return(substitute(Factor(var), list(var = x)))
    }
}

f <- a + b * c ~ d + e
update_formula(f)
# Factor(a) + Factor(b) * Factor(c) ~ Factor(d) + Factor(e)
```

The main idea is that each binary operator corresponds to a list of length 3. For example:

```
> as.list(f)
[[1]]
`~`

[[2]]
a + b * c

[[3]]
d + e

> as.list(f[[2]])
[[1]]
`+`

[[2]]
a

[[3]]
b * c

> as.list(f[[3]])
[[1]]
`+`

[[2]]
d

[[3]]
e
```

So we update the second and third component each time we encounter a binary operator.

To apply arbitrary transformation:

```
update_formula2 <- function(x, trans){
    if(length(x) == 3){
        x[[2]] <- update_formula2(x[[2]], trans)
        x[[3]] <- update_formula2(x[[3]], trans)
        return(x)
    }else{
        return(substitute(fun(var), list(fun = trans, var = x)))
    }
}

f <- a + b * c ~ d + e
update_formula2(f, quote(Factor))
# Factor(a) + Factor(b) * Factor(c) ~ Factor(d) + Factor(e)
update_formula2(f, quote(log))
# log(a) + log(b) * log(c) ~ log(d) + log(e)
```

Comment: I accepted the other answer because I'll probably end up using a simple `gsub`, but I want to say that your solution was very informative; I learned something useful while reading it. Thanks!